# Word that means make something available to all / to the working classes

Tags: single-word-requests

I am seeking a verb that essentially means ‘Bring to the reach of everybody’. For example:

> Travel was for the wealthy but the introduction of the package holiday xxxx travel.

Xxx is a word, like ‘democratised’, but it’s not democratised and I can’t think what it is! Any thoughts?

Comment: _Popularised_ isn’t far off, but the more common meaning of _popular_ (‘liked by many’ as opposed to ‘characterised by/available to the general public’) probably makes it too ambiguous here.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you. That is really not far off. I'm seeking the word that makes something available to the working classes.

Comment: 'Polo was once the sport of the very rich but cheap polo ponies has xxxxx’ the sport

Comment: 'de-classed' (NB sorry - every time I type a new line I start a new comment!!)

Comment: you almost want something to express how it made it accessible to all eg  introduction of the package holiday made travel accessible to all

Comment: There is always **vulgarized**, where the  Latin root *vulgus* refers to the common people. It would give your text a very different tone. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/vulgar

Comment: *Commodify* is a fairly recent coinage that is sometimes used that way.

Comment: @Smock, I honestly almost upvoted, but in which communist utopia is the working-class all? Or do you mean the above any the working, in a two party two class system, that is so dual you could almost think of double-speak? Good thinking, though, no need to give everything a name. It's pretty value free, just a gross generalization inviting *b-but*s. All interpretation is my own. Why not make it an

Comment: @vectory I think you've misunderstood. *X is available to group A(wealthy) in the morning, then made available to all in the afternoon*. Why would *all* not include group A in the afternoon?

Comment: Normalized or normalization might be contender this.

Answer (score 1):

**universalize**

> bring into universal use; make available for all.
> *attempts to universalize basic education*
>
> *Kalam announced that a cess would be proposed on all central taxes to
> finance the commitment to **universalise** access to basic education.*
>
> *It has been shown through research the world over that there are huge
> social benefits from **universalizing** elementary education.*
>
> *Suppose you tried to **universalize** college education - how many people
> would actually go for it?* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/universalize)

We humans do tend to aggrandize our planet, but as long as there isn't anyone around to complain, what the hey.

I had to look up *cess*: *(in Scotland, Ireland, and India) a tax or levy*. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cess). Evidently you can tax a tax.

Comment: The first good answer. // Does 'taxing a tax' mean you take from the Exchequer? Isn't that just re-allocation of Government spending? ... Or is it merely a tax hike? Seems like political  doubletalk.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the package holiday "**revolutionized**" travel.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/revolutionizing

Answer (score 0):

I found it remarkably difficult to come up with a *verb* that has this kind of specific meaning.

There is no verb form of the adjective *available*, which would be ideal.

---

However, in thinking of something that is at first available to only a few, but then becomes something routine or *common*, one verb is [**commonize**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonize):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to make (something) common, standard, or universal
>
> // Because the book is considered to be so highbrow I wanted to *“commonize”* it a little bit. I didn't want to fall into the trap of being inaccessible.
> — Kari Skogland, quoted in *The Calgary (Alberta) Herald*, 23 May 2008
>
> // We have to reuse and *commonize* what has worked and what has been well received by the customers.
> — Birgit Behrendt, quoted in Automotive News Europe, 13 June 2005

---

Ironically, it's not a common verb, but your sentence would become:

> Travel was for the wealthy but the introduction of the package holiday *commonized* travel.

---

Other less satisfactory verbs I had originally considered included *disinhibited, unleashed, derestricted, liberated, unbound, unchained, freed,* and *unfettered*.